# silverlight/windows phone 7 selectedIndex problems with button inside listbox

Tags: silverlight, listbox, windows-phone-7

I've got a listbox with a simple list of items.  On my xaml page, I have the following

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding firstName}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastName}"/>
                                    <Button BorderThickness="0" Click="buttonPerson_Click">
                                        <Image Source="delete-icon.png"/>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

In my codebehind, I try to grab the selectedIndex so I can remove the item from the collection that is bound to my listbox.

```
private void buttonPerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
                return;

            myPersonList.removeAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);

        }
```

However, no matter on which row I click the delete button, selectedIndex is always -1

what am I missing?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want by setting the Tag property of the button to your object like this:

```
<Button BorderThickness="0" Click="buttonPerson_Click" Tag="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}">
     <Image Source="delete-icon.png"/>
</Button>
```

Then in the eventhandler you can do this:

```
private void buttonPerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myPersonList.remove((sender as Button).Tag);
}
```

Not sure what your Person object is called so I didn't cast the Tag to it, but you will probably have to do that, but looks like you are comfortable with that.

---

*Is there a missing StackPanel start element in your XAML?  This is probably just an oversight, but could cause you some problems if this is your actual code.*

Comment: this answer has been pretty helpful.  What if I don't want to attach an entire object to the tag? what if I just want to attach a number..say..the selectedIndex?

Comment: I would avoid using the index (both because it's harder to do and less flexible as your code changes).  You could add an ID property (something unique) to your custom object and bind the tag to this.  Then you could either loop through the list and remove based on this ID, or use a dictionary with the key set to that ID.

Answer (score 2):

The sender will be the button you've clicked, its `DataContext` will be the item you want to delete and a typical `List` implementation will have a `Remove` method.  So something like this would work in the general case:-

```
 ((IList)myPersonList).Remove(((Button)sender).DataContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

The button is capturing the touch (click) event so the item is never getting selected.

Instead of using the SelectedIndex, you should work out which item to delete based on which button was clicked. (Do this by looking at the `sender` passed to the event handler.)

Answer (score 1):

I know you have an answer but this is yet another way to do what you ask.
You could also use the selecteditem property

```
private void buttonPerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        // Select the item in the listbox that was clicked
        listBox1.SelectedItem = ((Button)sender).DataContext;

        // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        // Cast you bound list datatype.
        myPersonList.remove(([myPersonList Type])listBox1.SelectedValue);

    }
```